# How big is Java 6SE?

Tags: java

I just asked a question about upgrading from 5 > 6

From what I can see 5 has 165 packages, over 3000 classes.  Can someone tell me how many packages and classes are in Java versions 6 and the new 7. I was not able to find this information any place.

thanks

Comment: Here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/api-jsp-136079.html

Answer (score 2):

Java SE 6:

- [203 packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-frame.html)
- [3793 classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html)

Java SE 7:

- [209 packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-frame.html)
- [4024 classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html)

Comment: Don't really know why the numbers matter w/r/t upgrading, though.

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 should be a bit bigger, not that much.

Java 7 will be lighter as it will become modular : 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2008/jw-08-java-modularity.html

Comment: Java 7 is already out, and modularity has been postponed. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: +1 @JB, that JW article is 3 years old...

Comment: Yep all the good stuff has been deferred to 8 sadly and modularization is one of them :/